# Getting single record in subquery

Tags: sql, db2

I have a DB2 database with multiple `user` records, which are related to a `newsletter` record through a couple intermediate tables.

My problem is that I need to get *just* the users where the latest `newsletter` they received was in the last week. I've been banging my head against this for hours and still haven't found a way to cleanly get the records I need. I thought this would be the solution, but I keep running into very generic errors that I don't really understand the cause of.

```
SELECT a.*, d.tech_id as newsletter FROM users a 
JOIN user_profile b ON b.tech_id = a.profile_id
JOIN user_contact c ON c.user_id = b.tech_id
JOIN (
    SELECT newsletters.tech_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp(tech_id) DESC) AS RN
      FROM NEWSLETTERS
) d ON d.tech_id  = c.newsletter_id
WHERE (timestamp(d.rn) < current_timestamp - 7 days)
```

Is there a better way to do this, or am I missing an obvious problem?

EDIT:

This is what I'd like to be doing, though it doesn't work right either:

```
SELECT a.* as newsletter FROM users a 
WHERE (
   SELECT MAX(timestamp(newsletters.tech_id))
   FROM newsletters
   WHERE newsletters.tech_id IN(
      SELECT newsletter_id FROM user_contact WHERE user_contact.profile_id = a.tech_id
   )
) < current_timestamp - 7 days
```

The structure is pretty straightforward. The `users` table has a foreign key of `profile_id` which is keyed to the `user_profile.tech_id`. The `user_contact.user_id` field is keyed to the `user_profile.tech_id`. And the `user_contact` table has a foreign key called `user_contact.newsletter_id` that is keyed to the `newsletters.tech_id`

Comment: What is the structure of your tables?

Comment: @imtheman-- added more details on the structure. thanks

Comment: Two things: 1) Avoid calling functions on anything used for joining or searching, since it usually prevents the optimizer from using indices 2) Your current statement is getting newsletters _older_ than one week, not _younger_ ("within the last week").

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  You ain't gettin' nuffin', because your statement isn't listing anything that appears to be a date/timestamp type.  Where's the relevant field (there's two potential places)?

Answer (score 0):

`RN` is a row number generated based on the latest timestamp of the column. It should not be compared with dates in the final `where` clause. However, in your `row_number` function, you have ordered by `timestamp(tech_id)` which won't work as expected if `tech_id` is not a `datetime` datatype.

As per your requirement, `row_number` isn't needed.

Try the query below.

```
SELECT a.*, d.tech_id as newsletter
FROM users a 
JOIN user_profile b ON b.tech_id = a.profile_id
JOIN user_contact c ON c.user_id = b.tech_id
JOIN NEWSLETTERS d ON d.tech_id  = c.newsletter_id
WHERE (timestamp(d.datecolumn) < current_timestamp - 7 days)
--change the d.datecolumn to the datetime column in the table
```

Comment: Thanks @vkp-- but I want ONLY the most recent `newsletter` record. I believe that this type of join will bring all of the records back. I need to know if the most recent newsletter was less than a week old.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use `GROUP BY`. Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM users a
JOIN (
   SELECT d.tech_id as newsletter, MAX(d.datecol) 
   FROM user_profile b
   JOIN user_contact c ON c.user_id = b.tech_id
   JOIN NEWSLETTERS d ON d.tech_id  = c.newsletter_id
   WHERE (timestamp(d.datecol) < current_timestamp - 7 days)
   GROUP BY d.tech_id
) e ON e.tech_id = a.profile_id
```